# Combinatronics: Pick n from m, x times with no sets containing duplicate pairs

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A little background...

I'm hosting a party - and I have 24 people coming, and 6 tables.

During the party, there are 6 sessions where people will switch tables.

I want it so that every person gets to sit on every table, and at every session they will be with no-one they've met before.

Is this possible?

If it's not possible, I want to put a constraint on the number of people they've met before on a table - is there any way to find the minimum for this constraint? (e.g. at most they will have already met 1 person on the table, 2 people, etc.)

I've tried computing with brute force, but with no luck.

Edit: A bit of further clarification.

Imagine it as speed dating, except that every person changes tables, and every person has to sit at every table without sitting at the same table as someone they've met before.

Edit2: A bit more clarification

This is similar to the Social golfer problem.

We have 24 golfers playing in groups of 4 on 6 courses. Each golfer should play on each course, and not have to play with the same person twice, or to minimize the amount that players play with the same person.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understood the problem, but if they change place 6 times, even if every time they get to sit with 2 new people, one person can sit at most with12 other people

Comment: Sorry, the need isn't to maximize the number of different people they sit with, but to minimize the number of people they sit with more than once - while making sure that everyone sits at every table.

Comment: The words "combinatorial design" should give you something to search for here.

Comment: Could be related to the well known school-girl-problem

Comment: I tried taking a 7-week solution to the social golfer problem and adding table assignments (leaving out one week since by then everyone must have sat at every table -- I tried varying which one was left out), but I kept running into contradictions that made it impossible to have everyone sit at new tables for more than a few weeks.